# How to find and read into files inside multiple .zip folders with Perl?

Tags: perl, unzip, file-handling, compression

I have a directory structure like this:

```
Sample1
  Subdir1
    file.txt
    file.jpg
    file.fastq
    directory1.zip
          file.txt
          file.csv
          result.html
          summary.txt
    directory2.zip
          file.txt
          file.csv
          result.html
          summary.txt
```

Once I am at the Subdir1 level, how can I find an uncompress the two .zip files, and save the two summary.txt files to two different filehandles?

This is for further reading into these two files and parsing them into an array.

I was asked to post what I have so far. It's very messy, but here goes:

```
my %cellHash = ();
while (my $cellDirectory = readdir(SEQ_RUN)) {
         %cellHash { $cellDirectory } = ()
         #Descend into "trimmed" subdirectory of cell.
    my $trimmedDirectory =  $cellDirectory . "/trimmed"
        opendir (TRIMMED_CELL_DIR, $trimmedDirectory) or die $!;
        # Read the 2 ZIP files
        while (my $fastQCzip = readdir(TRIMMED_CELL_DIR)) {
         #only if .zip  
        # File 1 always ends in _1_fastqc.zip
        # File 2 always ends in _2_fastqc.zip

my $summaryFastQC = Archive::Zip->new();
unless ( $summaryFastQC->read( $fastQCzip ) == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'read error'
    }
# Parse output: cellHash {cellName} [ R1 TESTS ] [ R2 TESTS ]
open QUALITY_SUMMARY, "filename.txt" or die $!;
```

Comment: post what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the zip-files can more easily be done using the module File::Find.

The code block, that is given to search for the files can even be created from the usual find command by passing it to find2perl.

For example: 
    find2perl find . -name "*.zip"

produces:

```
sub wanted {
    /^.*\.zip\z/s
    && print("$name\n");
}
```

So you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;


sub wanted {
    /^.*\.zip\z/s
    && print("$File::Find::dir/$_\n");
}

my @dirs = ("somedir", "anotherdir");

my @zips = find(\&wanted, @dirs);

print "@zips\n";
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html

Then, to save the instances of summary.txt, you would scan the archives for that name and save the files to some directory. To avoid overwriting you can keep them apart by some arbitrary extension:

```
my $wanted = "summary.txt";
my $suffix = 0;
foreach my $zipname (@zips)
{
    my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($zipname);
    foreach my $member ($zip->members)
    {
        next unless ($member->fileName =~ /\/$wanted$/);

        $suffix++;
        if ($member->extractToFileNamed("$wanted.$suffix") != 'AZ_OK') {
            die("Could not create $newname");
        }
    }
}
```

See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=104653